# Configure Kubernetes Job with ArgoCD

Tags: argocd

**Requirement**

- I need to run a `Job` which is defined in it's own helm chart.
- The `Job` imports some data in my database.
- It should run in my release in a specific wave.
- The `Job` needs to be deleted before a new run, because kubernetes doesn't allow to update existing Jobs.
- If the `Job` isn't deleted I get this error: `field is immutable`
- **Important**: The `Job` should only get deleted before the new run, but not directly after it's own run, so that I'm able to inspect the completed pod and I see, that it succeeded.

**Current Solution**

I've defined an `Application` with these sync options (via app-of-apps pattern):

```
syncOptions:
  - CreateNamespace=true
  - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true
  - ServerSideApply=true
  - Validate=true
  - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
  - PruneLast=true
```

The `Job` uses this sync options:

```
annotations:
  argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
  argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: BeforeHookCreation
```

The idea is, that BeforeHookCreation deletes the `Job` before a new `Job` is created.

**Result**

- This works if a execute a manual sync via the GUI.
- But if the sync is triggered automatically, I get an error:
  Failed Event: `one or more objects failed to apply (dry run) (retried 5 times).`
  Message: `... field is immutable`

**Question**

- Is there a way to avoid the dry run or is there another solution to avoid this error?
- Or should I choose a different setup for my requirements?

Comment: So I've found a solution (see my answer), but nevertheless I'm curious, if there are other or even better solutions. The most obvious solution using _replace_ unfortunately didn't help for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set

```
- ServerSideApply=false
```

and to keep all other options as stated in the question.

Comment: But honestly, I don't know why this helps. Is there only a dry run with server side apply?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `replace=true` should work here. See the docs for reference - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#replace-resource-instead-of-applying-changes

Comment: That sounds absolute reasonble, but sometimes it ended with error "when replacing "/dev/...": jobs.batch "my-job" not found". So the Job was perhaps deleted by the replace before the hook-delete-policy could delete the Job. When I use replace without hook-delete-policy I also get the "field is immutable" error. But perhaps I just did a stupid error.